# MySQL error when quoting `identifiers`

Tags: mysql

Somehow I can't use quotes in queries.
For example, a simple query:

```
create table `T1`( `f1` integer );
```

Gives an error:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near '`T1`( `f1` integer )' at line 1.
```

Why does this happen?
I'm using MySQL server 5.5.20, and MySQL Workbench.

Comment: have you tried removing the '' from all the names?

Comment: My best guess is that you have some non-printable characters in there, because I had no problem creating the table with your code.

Comment: What statement is before this one? A `;` is missing there probably.

Comment: gview - You are right!!! :) 'nonbreaking space' stands after `table`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is correct,
but you had an NBSP after `table`.